# Spring MVC RESTful web services with Jackson: How to restrict to subset of URLs

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

Following the steps outlined here http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program , I've been able to setup my RESTful WS exactly how I want it.

Now, I want to make this app context a hybrid of RESTful WS (under a specific URL prefix /myapp/rest/) and standard MVC mappings for the rest of the site.

But from the servlet-context XML file, I can't really make out how to restrict `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`to only apply to a certain URL prefix.

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

Is there anything else that I should be checking on here?

Thanks
Wong

Comment: so you want to use rest service for a particular user path only like `/myapp/rest/` and also mvc functionality like form post  both using same spring mvc application !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both SpringMVC style controllers and SpringMVC REST style controllers in the same application. In fact you can write one SpringMVC handler method and a REST Endpoint in same controller too.

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String homePage(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("data",someObject);
        return "home"; //this will render the view home.jsp
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
        //persist user
        return user; //this will return JSON/XML based representation of User object
    }   

}
```

Observe the use of **@RequestBody** and **@ResponseBody** annotations for REST style handler methods.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the answer I was looking for: to find the exact hook / annotation that defines that a method is RESTful or just standard MVC. Thanks!